# Random number generator that returns only one number each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, generator

Does Python have a random number generator that returns only one random integer number each time when `next()` function is called? Numbers **should not repeat** and the generator should return random integers in the interval `[1, 1 000 000]` that are unique.

I need to generate more than million different numbers and that sounds as if it is very memory consuming in case all the number are generated at same time and stored in a list.

Comment: Maybe use https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html? `uuid.uuid4()`

Comment: how about extracting the distinct number from the time function? `print "%.20f" % time.time()`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: I think it's important to know what kind of random numbers you want. If you simply use `random.random()` to get a floating point value in the range between 0 and 1 you probably don't need to care about uniques (it's *really unlikely* that you get the same number twice) but if you want to get integers (say from 0-10 000 000) it's not that uncommon to get at least a few duplicates even if the range is ten times bigger. Without these details any answer will be speculative. You can increase your chances to get a really helpful answer by providing more of your _actual_ requirements.

Comment: @MSeifert thank you allready edited questions. I need integers that are not repeated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a full period. This will allow you to get a pseudo-random sequence of non-repeating numbers in your target number range.

Implementing a LCG is actually very simple, and looks like this:

```
def lcg(a, c, m, seed = None):
    num = seed or 0
    while True:
        num = (a * num + c) % m
        yield num
```

Then, it just comes down to choosing the correct values for `a`, `c`, and `m` to guarantee that the LCG will generate a full period (which is the only guarantee that you get non-repeating numbers). As the Wikipedia article explains, the following three conditions need to be true:

1. `m` and `c` need to be relatively prime.
2. `a - 1` is divisible by all prime factors of `m`
3. `a - 1` is divisible by 4, if `m` is also divisible by 4.

The first one is very easily guaranteed by simply choosing a prime for `c`. Also, this is the value that can be chosen last, and this will ultimately allow us to mix up the sequence a bit.

The relationship between `a - 1` and `m` is more complicated though. In a full period LCG, `m` is the length of the period. Or in other words, it is the number range your numbers come from. So this is what you are usually choosing first. In your case, you want `m` to be around `1000000`. Choosing exactly your maximum number might be difficult since that restricts you a lot (in both your choice of `a` and also `c`), so you can also choose numbers larger than that and simply skip all numbers outside of your range later.

Let’s choose `m = 1000000` now though. The prime factors of `m` are `2` and `5`. And it’s also obviously divisible by `4`. So for `a - 1`, we need a number that is a multiple of `2 * 2 * 5` to satisfy the conditions 2 and 3. Let’s choose `a - 1 = 160`, so `a = 161`.

For `c`, we are using a random prime that’s somewhere in between of our range: `c = 506903`

Putting that into our LCG gives us our desired sequence. We can choose any seed value from the range (`0 <= seed <= m`) as the starting point of our sequence.

So let’s try it out and verify that what we thought of actually works. For this purpose, we are just collecting all numbers from the generator in a set until we hit a duplicate. At that point, we should have `m = 1000000` numbers in the set:

```
>>> g = lcg(161, 506903, 1000000)
>>> numbers = set()
>>> for n in g:
        if n in numbers:
            raise Exception('Number {} already encountered before!'.format(n))
        numbers.add(n)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception('Number {} already encountered before!'.format(n))
Exception: Number 506903 already encountered before!
>>> len(numbers)
1000000
```

And it’s correct! So we did create a pseudo-random sequence of numbers that allowed us to get non-repeating numbers from our range `m`. Of course, by design, this sequence will be always the same, so it is only random once when you choose those numbers. You can switch up the values for `a` and `c` to get different sequences though, as long as you maintain the properties mentioned above.

---

The big benefit of this approach is of course that you do not need to store all the previously generated numbers. It is a constant space algorithm as it only needs to remember the initial configuration and the previously generated value.

It will also not deteriorate as you get further into the sequence. This is a general problem with solutions that just keep generating a random number until a new one is found that hasn’t been encountered before. This is because the longer the list of generated numbers gets, the less likely you are going to hit a numbers that’s not in that list with an evenly distributed random algorithm. So getting the 1000000th number will likely take you a long time to generate with memory based random generators.

But of course, having this simply algorithm which just performs some multiplication and some addition does not appear very random. But you have to keep in mind that this is actually the basis for most pseudo-random number generators out there. So `random.random()` uses something like this internally. It’s just that the `m` is *a lot larger*, so you don’t notice it there.

Comment: This is a great answer. There's one minor thing missing that I stumbled upon and could sting someoen who experiments with this. You actually can't make a `m` a prime if you want to specify any seed value. The period will be full only if the `m` has repeated prime divisors. So anything that's divisable by 4 will work for example because it has 2 & 2 in it's divisors

Comment: Yes, `m` should not practically be a prime because `a - 1` needs to be divisible by its prime factors (as per rule 2). If you have chosen good values (like the ones in my example), you _can_ choose any seed value though since the repeating sequence will just start from that number then.

Comment: You can check my one below, it seems that I invented a unique algorithm for this purpose, and it doesn't have any restrictions (e. g. prime numbers, etc.). I'm wondering if there's a name for this approach?

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin Of course, a LCG is not the only way to solve this problem but it has many benefits, e.g. it being a constant time and space algorithm and it having a tiny amount of state (just the previously generated number). Compare this to approaches that have to store a shuffled list, or in your case the state of recursive generator functions, and you can see that it can be very useful for many situations. And as I said, by relying on `random`, you are actually building your algorithm on top of something very similar to a LCG anyway.

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin As for the “restrictions” of an LCG: You don’t actually need a prime number, you just need to choose two numbers that are [relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). It’s just by choosing a prime number, you are solving this in a very easy matter. And if you need certain boundaries of the generated numbers, you can always choose a larger output set and throw away all numbers that do not fit into your bounds (that’s what `random` does itself too).

Answer (score 2):

If you really care about the memory you could use a `NumPy` array (or a Python [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)).

A one million NumPy array of `int32` (more than enough to contain integers between 0 and 1 000 000) will only consume ~4MB, Python itself would require ~36MB (roughly 28byte per integer and 8 byte for each list element + overallocation) for an identical list:

```
>>> # NumPy array
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.int32).nbytes
4 000 000

>>> # Python list
>>> import sys
>>> import random
>>> l = list(range(1000000))
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> size = sys.getsizeof(l)                         # size of the list
>>> size += sum(sys.getsizeof(item) for item in l)  # size of the list elements
>>> size
37 000 108
```

You only want unique values and you have a consecutive range (1 million requested items and 1 million different numbers), so you could simply shuffle the range and then yield items from your shuffled array:

```
def generate_random_integer():
    arr = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.int32)
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    yield from arr 
    # yield from is equivalent to:
    # for item in arr:     
    #     yield item
```

And it can be called using `next`:

```
>>> gen = generate_random_integer()
>>> next(gen)
443727
```

However that will throw away the performance benefit of using NumPy, so in case you want to use NumPy don't bother with the generator and just perform the operations (vectorized - if possible) on the array. It consumes much less memory than Python and it could be orders of magnitude faster (factors of 10-100 faster are not uncommon!).

Comment: good answer, but I wonder, why the generator function?, also notice the python3 tag, you can simply do `yield from arr`

Comment: @DanielSanchez You're right. I haven't looked at the tags. The generator is included because he specifically asked for one: " that returns only one random integer number each time when next() function is called".

Comment: Yeah, i did not saw that, you got my points, very interesting aproach with numpy :)

Answer (score 1):

For a large number of non-repeating random numbers use an encryption.  With a given key, encrypt the numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...  Since encryption is uniquely reversible then each encrypted number is guaranteed to be unique, provided you use the same key.  For 64 bit numbers use DES.  For 128 bit numbers use AES.  For other size numbers use some Format Preserving Encryption.  For pure numbers you might find Hasty Pudding cipher useful as that allows a large range of different bit sizes and non-bit sizes as well, like [0..5999999].

Keep track of the key and the last number you encrypted.  When you need a new unique random number just encrypt the next number you haven't used so far.

Comment: Good ieda but I used LCG in the end because it was simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your numbers should fit in a 64bit integer, one million of them stored in a list would be up to 64 mega bytes plus the list object overhead, if your processing computer can afford that the easyest way is to use shuffle:

```
import random
randInts = list(range(1000000))
random.shuffle(randInts)
print(randInts)
```

Note that the other method is to keep track of the previously generated numbers, which will get you to the point of having all of them stored too.

Comment: Python integers aren't 64bit, on my computer they are 28 **bytes**.

Comment: @MSeifert, actually yes, i wasnt pretty sure so i was researching it,  thanks for confirming that, ill update the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed that function, and to my huge surprise I haven't found anything that would suit my needs. @poke's answer didn't satisfy me because I needed to have precise borders, and other ones which included lists caused heaped memory.

Initially, I needed a function that would generate numbers from `a` to `b`, where `a - b` could be anything from `0` to `2^32 - 1`, which means the range of those numbers could be as high as maximal 32-bit unsigned integer.

The idea of my own algorithm is simple both to understand and implement. It's a binary tree, where the next branch is chosen by 50/50 chance boolean generator. Basically, we divide all numbers from `a` to `b` into two branches, then decide from which one we yield the next value, then do that recursively until we end up with single nodes, which are also being picked up by random.

The depth of recursion is:

[image: \log+_{2}+(b - a)]

, which implies that for the given stack limit of 256, your highest range would be 2^256, which is impressive.

Things to note:

1. `a` must be lesser or equal `b` - otherwise no output will be displayed.
2. Boundaries  are included, meaning `unique_random_generator(0, 3)` will generate `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

## TL;DR - here's the code

```py
import math, random

# a, b - inclusive
def unique_random_generator(a, b):
    
    # corner case on wrong input
    if a > b:
        return

    # end node of the tree
    if a == b:
        yield a
        return
    
    # middle point of tree division
    c = math.floor((a + b) / 2)
    
    generator_left = unique_random_generator(a, c) # left branch - contains all the numbers between 'a' and 'c'
    generator_right = unique_random_generator(c + 1, b) # right branch - contains all the numbers between 'c + 1' and 'b'

    has_values = True
    while (has_values):
        # decide whether we pick up a value from the left branch, or the right
        decision = bool(random.getrandbits(1))

        if decision:
            next_left = next(generator_left, None)
            
            # if left branch is empty, check the right one
            if next_left == None:
                next_right = next(generator_right, None)
                
                # if both empty, current recursion's dessicated
                if next_right == None:
                    has_values = False
                else:
                    yield next_right
            else:
                yield next_left
                next_right = next(generator_right, None)
                
                if next_right != None:
                    yield next_right
        else:
            next_right = next(generator_right, None)
            
            # if right branch is empty, check the left one
            if next_right == None:
                next_left = next(generator_left, None)
                
                # if both empty, current recursion's dessicated
                if next_left == None:
                    has_values = False
                else:
                    yield next_left
            else:
                yield next_right
                next_left = next(generator_left, None)
                
                if next_left != None:
                    yield next_left
```

Usage:

```py
for i in unique_random_generator(0, 2**32):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

# number of random entries 
x = 1000

# The set of all values 
y = {}
while (x > 0) :
    a = random.randint(0 , 10**10)
    if a not in y :  
        a -= 1
```

This way you are sure you have perfectly random unique values
`x` represents the number of values you want

Comment: If I understand your solution right I have to store all numbers that I allready generated in dictionary `y`? That is something I do not want to do since I want to have nice solution that does not spend too much memory.

Answer (score -4):

You can easily make one yourself:

```
from random import random

def randgen():
    while True:
        yield random()


ran = randgen()
next(ran)  
next(ran)
...
```

Comment: `random.random` does not return an int, and is also not guaranteed to produce unique numbers (otherwise it wouldn’t be random).